# Importing modules works on Shell but not on the Interpreter

Tags: python, module, wand

I'm trying to use the module `Wand` and when I import it from shell it works just fine. But when I try to use it on my IDE (PyCharm) it simply says there's no such module. I have no idea why.

```
$ python 
>>> import wand
```

But on the IDE, if I try to import wand it simply says `No module named wand`

Comment: Is the IDE using the same python executable? `import sys;print(sys.version)` can tell you. Is `Wand` installed or is it in your local directory? The IDE may have a different working directory `print(os.getcwd())` or may not put it in the python path.

Comment: Can you check if the python interpreter being used on shell and pycharm are the same? on shell you can do "which python", and pycharm has options to select an interpreter if there are multiple installed.

Comment: Both are using python 3.7